# the whole text gets cleared when trying to clear the selected word or character

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fabricjs

I am using fabric js with reactjs for adding the text to canvas. The text is added but when i try to clear the character or selected words, the whole text gets cleared. I saw some of the resources regarding this but i am using reactjs so it was hard to resolve this issue for me. Here is how i have done

```
class ImageBoard extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selected: undefined
    };
  }

  handleDeleteKey = event => {
    if (event.keyCode === 46 || event.keyCode === 8) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (this.state.selected !== undefined) {
        this.canvas.remove(this.state.selected);
        this.setState({ selected: undefined });
      }
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");
    document.addEventListener("keydown", this.handleDeleteKey, false);
    this.canvas.on("object:selected", e =>
      this.setState({ selected: e.target })
    );
    this.canvas.on("selection:cleared", e =>
      this.setState({ selected: undefined })
    );
    this.canvas.setBackgroundColor(
      "rgba(255, 73, 64, 0.6)",
      this.canvas.renderAll.bind(this.canvas)
    );
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.images !== this.props.images) {
      this.setCanvasBackground(this.props.images, this.canvas);
    }
  }

  addText = () => {
    let text = new fabric.IText("Double click me to change the text!", {
      fontSize: 28,
      fontWeight: 600,
      left: 100,
      top: 100,
      fill: "black",
      width: 20,
      height: 20
    });
    this.canvas.add(text);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <Column width={80}>
          <canvas
            id="canvas"
            ref={el => (this.canvasEl = el)}
            width={580}
            height={400}
            className="z-depth-1"
          />
        </Column>
        <Filter
          addText={this.addText}
        />
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ImageBoard);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're removing a selected object in the `delete`/`backspace` key handler, it's not unexpected that when you're trying to clear text characters with `delete`/`backspace`, the whole text gets removed. The condition check `if (this.state.selected !== undefined)` is not enough because when you enter text editing mode, the text object is still selected.

However, you can additionally check IText's [`isEditing`](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.IText.html#isEditing) property to see if the selected object is also in the editing mode:

```
  handleDeleteKey = event => {
    if (event.keyCode === 46 || event.keyCode === 8) {
      if (this.state.selected !== undefined && !this.state.selected.isEditing) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.canvas.remove(this.state.selected);
        this.setState({ selected: undefined });
      }
    }
  };
```

Here's a working snippet to demonstrate:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selected: undefined
    };
  }

  handleDeleteKey = event => {
    
    if (event.keyCode === 46 || event.keyCode === 8) {
      if (this.state.selected !== undefined && !this.state.selected.isEditing) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.canvas.remove(this.state.selected);
        this.setState({ selected: undefined });
      }
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");
    document.addEventListener("keydown", this.handleDeleteKey, false);
    this.canvas.on("object:selected", e =>
      this.setState({ selected: e.target })
    );
    this.canvas.on("selection:cleared", e =>
      this.setState({ selected: undefined })
    );
    this.canvas.setBackgroundColor(
      "rgba(255, 73, 64, 0.6)",
      this.canvas.renderAll.bind(this.canvas)
    );
  }

  addText = () => {
    let text = new fabric.IText("Double click me to change the text!", {
      fontSize: 28,
      fontWeight: 600,
      left: 20,
      top: 20,
      fill: "black",
      width: 20,
      height: 20
    });
    this.canvas.add(text);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <canvas
          id="canvas"
          ref={el => (this.canvasEl = el)}
          width={400}
          height={170}
        />
        <button onClick={this.addText}>
          add
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.6.0/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'></div>
```